# Is there a way to click a event from code in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building a game in unity and I need a certain event to be fired when the game object reaches a certain point with user input. is there any way to do it in c#

For example, in javascript, we can add the click() function which fires that on the click function. Is there a way to do it in c#

Comment: `is there any way to do it in c#` .. there are many ways depending on your platform and framework ..  I guess you rather want to ask how to do that in Unity in specific -> [Unity UI System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate code from onClick method to another method. Then you can call the method when you want.

```
// METHOD TO CALL WHEN CLICKED
public void onClickMethod(){
    method();
}
private void method(){
    /* CODE HERE */
}
// EXAMPLE
void Update(){
    if(ex > 5) method();
}
```

I didnt use Unity3D last time. I guess you can't just call onClickMethod()?

Answer (score 2):

There's an example from Unity Documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

`Example.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Make sure to attach these Buttons in the Inspector
    public Button firstButton, secondButton, thirdButton;

    void Start()
    {
        //Calls the TaskOnClick/TaskWithParameters/ButtonClicked method when you click the Button
        firstButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        secondButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { TaskWithParameters("Hello"); });
        thirdButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(42));
        thirdButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
    }

    void TaskWithParameters(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log(message);
    }

    void ButtonClicked(int buttonNo)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button clicked = " + buttonNo);
    }
}
```

Of course, `Example.TaskOnClick()` could be called manually from other places in code & not only when the button is clicked.

Comment: In general I would rather reference an [up-to-date API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Button.html) ;) Unity 5.3 is 5 years ago ...

Comment: Ty, edited answer.